How to reload the database after copying it from RAW folder?
I'm currently building an app with databases and I'm struggling to find a solution with, what I think is, a simple problem.
I'm initializing the databases with:
// First database, no problems
        DatabaseHelper currencyDatabase = new DatabaseHelper(context, "currencies.db", 1, new String[]{TABLE_CURRENCIES}, new String[]{
                "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_CURRENCIES + "(" +
                        CURRENCIES_ID + " TEXT PRIMARY KEY," +
                        CURRENCIES_NAME + " TEXT," +
                        CURRENCIES_SYMBOL + " REAL," +
                        CURRENCIES_NATIVE + " TEXT," +
                        CURRENCIES_CODE + " INTEGER," +
                        CURRENCIES_PLURAL + " TEXT" +
                        ")"

        });
        currencyDatabase.copyDatabaseFromRaw(currencyDatabase.getReadableDatabase(), R.raw.currencies);
        currenciesDatabase = currencyDatabase.getWritableDatabase();
        currenciesList = getCurrenciesList();
        currencyModels = getCurrencies();


Here both currenciesList and currencyModels are empty.
The problem is not the query in the database itself because it works the second time. The problem is, after copying the database, the lists are empty and when creating/copying the databases the app crashes, when I re-launch it everything works normally.
The DatabaseHelper is just
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "database.db";
    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    public static int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static String[] TABLE;
    private static String[] CREATE_TABLE;
    private Context context;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context, boolean addID) {
        this(context, DATABASE_NAME, DATABASE_VERSION, "", "", addID);
        CREATE_TABLE = new String[]{};
        this.context = context;
    }

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context, String databaseName, int databaseVersion, String[] table, String[] tableColumns) {
        super(context, databaseName.endsWith(".db") ? databaseName : databaseName + ".db", null, databaseVersion);
        TABLE = table;
        DATABASE_VERSION = databaseVersion;
        CREATE_TABLE = tableColumns;
        this.context = context;
    }

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context, String databaseName, int databaseVersion, String table, String tableColumns, boolean addID) {
        super(context, databaseName.endsWith(".db") ? databaseName : databaseName + ".db", null, databaseVersion);
        TABLE[0] = table;
        DATABASE_VERSION = databaseVersion;
        CREATE_TABLE[0] = buildTable(tableColumns, addID, table);
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void copyDatabaseFromRaw(SQLiteDatabase db, @RawRes int rawID) {
        InputStream myInput = null;
        OutputStream myOutput = null;

        db.beginTransactionNonExclusive();
        try {
            myInput = context.getResources().openRawResource(rawID);
            myOutput = Files.newOutputStream(Paths.get(db.getPath()));
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
            myOutput.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new Error("copyDatabaseFromRaw" + " Error copying database");
        } finally {
            try {
                if (myOutput != null) {
                    myOutput.close();
                }
                if (myInput != null) {
                    myInput.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                throw new Error("copyDatabaseFromRaw" + " Error closing streams");
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        for (String s : CREATE_TABLE) {
            db.execSQL(s);
        }
    }

    private String buildTable(String columns, boolean addID, String table) {
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(columns)) {
            return "CREATE TABLE " + table + (addID ? "(" + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT)" : "");
        } else {
            return "CREATE TABLE " + table + (addID ? "(" + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " : "") + columns + ")";
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

Edit:
Now I use this but I'm sure I can improve it, especially the String outFileName = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases /currencies.db"; part
private void copyDatabase(Context context, int currencies) {
    InputStream mInput = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.currencies);
    String outFileName = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases /currencies.db";
    OutputStream mOutput;
    try {
        mOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    byte[] mBuffer = new byte[1024];
    int mLength;
    while (true) {
        try {
            if (!((mLength = mInput.read(mBuffer)) > 0)) break;
            mOutput.write(mBuffer, 0, mLength);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
    try {
        mOutput.flush();
        mOutput.close();
        mInput.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}


A few things.
1)If you're copying the db from raw, you shouldn't create the DBHelper until AFTER the db is copied.  Otherwise the file references won't be right, it will likely point to a version of the file it created and you then overwrote.  The copyFromRaw function shouldn't even be a function on the DatabaseHelper, as the DBHelper is meant to access an existing DB or create a new one when the instance is created, not a place to copy files around.
2)There's no reason for your copyFromRaw function to make a transaction.  And if it does create a transaction, it should also commit or revert it.  An unfinished transaction is always problematic.

Okay, I've kinda solved it but the copy looks like in the edit, is there a way to improve it?
